# Sequelize join permissions table with overrides

Tags: sql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create a permissions system, where I have a table of default permissions, and a table storing overridden values for those permissions.

I just can't seem to figure out the correct associations, and logic to return the complete set of permissions.

```
// permissions
id | key | value
________________
1  | 'a' | 0
2  | 'b' | 2
3  | 'c' | 5

// overrides
id | key | value
________________
3  | 'c' | 10

// results
id | key | value
________________
1  | 'a' | 0
2  | 'b' | 2
3  | 'c' | 10
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion, assuming that the tables can be joined by `id`. (if they must be joined by `key` then the association would be different).

```
Permissions.belongsTo(Overrides);

Persmissions.findAll({
      raw: true,
      include: { 
          model: Overrides, 
          required: false,
          attributes: [['value', 'override_val' ]]
        },
        attributes: [
            'id', 'key', 'value',
            [Sequelize.literal('case when override.value is not null then override.value else value end'), 'final_value']
        ]
    });
```

The output shows both values and the derived final value (so you can verify it works).  HTH